# Why we can access page via JavaScript menu while can't open page directly?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

We try to do scape for a web page after login. In this website menu use javascript code as below to go to other website pages.

```
    <div id="mCSB_2_container" class="mCSB_container" style="position:relative; top:0; right:0;" dir="rtl">
    <ul id="ctl00_ulUserMenu" class="menu">
    <li id="divMenuItem_1">
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('MenuItemRedirect','UsersManagement/UserInfoManagement.aspx');">بياناتي الشخصية 
</a></li>
```

When we try to access using full URL (appears in a browser after the targeted page load) https://*******/UsersManagement/UserInfoManagement.aspx , I can't reach the same page and I got the below error msg.

[image]

any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: because you're GETting a POST url?

Comment: it could be solved... so we can access the target page using URL

Comment: Yes, you have to do a POST, not a GET